# How to compare 3 value in this way?

Tags: javascript

I need a way to compare 3 values in a short way like this:

```
'aaa'=='aaa'=='aaa'
false
```

but as you can see, it doesn't work. Why?

With 2 values it does work obviously:

```
'aaa'=='aaa'
true
```

Comment: Because `'aaa' == 'aaa'`, it evaluates into `true == 'aaa'` which is false.  If you want to check that 3 variables are all the same, do `if (a == b && b == c) {}`

Comment: `'aaa' === 'aaa' && 'aaa' === 'aaa'`

Comment: @Archer is there not a short way to compare 3 value in a similar way?

Comment: Yes - see the linked duplicate question, or the extra bit I added to my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `'aaa'=='aaa'=='aaa'` is evaluated as `('aaa'=='aaa')=='aaa'`.

The sub-expression in parentheses evaluates to `true` and it becomes `true=='aaa'` which is `false` because when compares two values of different types, JavaScript first [converts one of them or both to a common type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators). It converts the boolean `true` to the number `1` and the string `'aaa'` to the number `0` which are, obviously, not equal.

What you need is

```js
console.log('aaa'=='aaa' && 'aaa'=='aaa')
```

Comment: `2==2==2 => false`, `1==1==1 => true`. Another pitfall of OP's attempt.

Answer (score 4):

Comparing of first two values evaluates to `true` and then that `true` is compared with `"aaa"` which evaluates to `false`.

To make it correct you can write:

```js
const a = 'aaa';
const b = 'aaa';
const c = 'aaa';

console.log(a === b && b === c); //true
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have those strings stored in variables you can do

```js
let a = 'aaa', b = 'aaa', c = 'aaa'

console.log(a === b && b === c) // true
```

Comment: note that i use strict equality (===) as discussed in [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Answer (score 0):

You can put all values in an Array and then use `Array.prototype.every()` function to test if all satisfy the condition defined in the callback you pass to it:

```js
let a = 'aaa', b = 'aaa', c = 'aaa'

let arr = [a, b, c]

let arr2 = [1, 2, 1]

console.log(arr.every(i => [arr[0]].includes(i)))
console.log(arr2.every(i => [arr2[0]].includes(i)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you may get the unique values from a given sequence, and if you get a single element is because all equal:

```js
const same = xs => new Set (xs).size === 1

const x = 'aaa'
const y = 'aaa'
const z = 'aaa'

const areSame = same ([ x, y, z ])

console.log(areSame)

const x_ = 'aaa'
const y_ = 'bbb'
const z_ = 'aaa'

const areSame_ = same ([ x_, y_, z_ ])

console.log (areSame_)
```

#### With variadic arguments

```js
const same = (...xs) => new Set (xs).size === 1

const x = 'aaa'
const y = 'aaa'
const z = 'aaa'

const areSame = same (x, y, z)

console.log(areSame)

const x_ = 'aaa'
const y_ = 'bbb'
const z_ = 'aaa'

const areSame_ = same (x_, y_, z_)

console.log (areSame_)
```